# Inject and Execute javascript into iframe

Tags: javascript, function, iframe, inject

I am getting a string of HTML from an api and I need to pass that into an iframe on my page.  While doing that, I also need to inject some javascript code to the head and body of the iframe.

I've been able to successfully do this by the following.  I am using React here, but it shouldn't make a difference...

```
return (
    <iframe id="iframe" />
)
```

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    let template = "<html><head></head><body><div id="content">hello world</div></body></html>"
    //really this is my response from an api call so it's a huge string of a complete HTML page 

    drawTemplateWindow(template)
})
```

And this is where things aren't working...

```
const drawTemplateWindow = (string) => {
    let iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
    let head = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('head');
    let body = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    let externalScripts = document.createElement('script');
    let editorScript = document.createElement('script');
    // set iframe content from template
    iframe.contentWindow.document.write(string)
    // add external EditorJS Script
    externalScripts.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/editorjs@latest'
    // add externalScripts to head
    head[0].appendChild(externalScripts)

    if (document.readyState === "complete" || document.readyState === "loaded") {
        console.log('have we loaded yet?')
        editorScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        editorScript.text = `
                // EditorJS should be defined in externalScripts include above
                let editor = new EditorJS('content') 
            `
    }

    // add editor script to end of body
    body[0].appendChild(editorScript);
}
```

I see the externalScript being appended to the Head, and the editor scripts being appended to the end of the body.  I can also see my console log that the frame has loaded completely.

I am getting an error that EditorJS isn't defined, or any script I throw in.  I've tried to create a local script with an alert function and pass that but it too fails and says that function is undefined.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think you need to set `head` and `body` *after* you use `iframe.contentWindow.document.write(string)`

Comment: @Barmar They are set after... They are defined before, is that what you mean?  Define them after setting string to the document?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You define and set them at the same time: `let body = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body');`

Comment: When you use `document.write()` it rebuilds the DOM, which creates new head and body elements.

Comment: You can also then use `iframe.contentWindow.document.head` and `iframe.contentWindow.document.body`